# How can I create a symlink/junction to an executable (in Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, junction

When I try I get an error when trying to run the executable.
For example,

```
mklink /j foo.exe c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
Junction created for foo.exe <<===>> c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

c:\P\npp>foo.exe
'foo.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Are junctions not supported for executables?  I'm guessing they are not.

(Q) Is there a way to create a link to an executable so my script that uses
`start c:\p\npp\notepad++.exe` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for
[mklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink)
says :

```
/j  Creates a Directory Junction.
```

So this is not for files.

The documentation for the
[start command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)
gives its syntax:

```
 START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
```

So your command could be :

```
start "" "c:\p\npp\notepad++.exe"
```

Comment: Doh!  Hand to forhead.

Comment: Just as an FYI.  I needed admin rights to create a hard-link.